# <option> value not being set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data returned by an ajax call, I am creating an option(dropdown select) element for each returned row of data, I need to make one of them default selected based on text. But value does not get assigned to the one I made "selected". Below is my code:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(r.d), function (key, value) {
  if (value == 'Username') {
    $('#ddlcriteria1')
      .append($('<option selected="selected">', { value: key })
        .text(value));
  }
  else {
    $('#ddlcriteria1')
      .append($('<option>', { value: key })
        .text(value));
  }
});
```

I am adding an option element for each returned row, and making the default selected one as "Username". When I look at the DOM after this has been added. I see this:

```
  <option value="1">First Name</option>
  <option value="2">Last Name</option>
  <option selected="selected">Username</option>
  <option value="4">Email</option>
  <option value="8">Department</option>
  <option value="9">Status</option>
  <option value="10">Position</option>
  <option value="11">Role</option>
  <option value="12">User Group</option>
  <option value="13">Course Code</option>
  <option value="15">Enrollment Location</option>
  <option value="16">Organization</option>
```

The option element with "Username" text does not have a value assigned, any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `selected` attribute in the object as well, like this:

```
$('<option>', { value: key, selected: true })
```

Comment: @Phani instead of doing an if statement, just do `selected: (value == 'Username')`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, of getting rid of if statement altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Make it good:

```
var optionElement = $('<option/>').attr({
                                     "selected":"selected", 
                                     "value": key
                                   });
$('#ddlcriteria1')
  .append(optionElement)
    .text(value));
```

With your code you are overriding the last properties

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
$.each(JSON.parse(r.d), function (key, value) {
  if (value == 'Username') {
    $('#ddlcriteria1')
      .append($('<option selected="selected" value='+ key+'>')
        .text(value));
  }
  else {
    $('#ddlcriteria1')
      .append($('<option>', { value: key })
        .text(value));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very much your code, but you are ask if value is Username I don't see a value like Username, because the value is missing in the dom maybe...

If your select id is ddlcriteria1 you can select the value to this form.

```
  if (value == 'Username') {
    $('#ddlcriteria1').val('Username');

  }
```

it's all you need

If your code is good you can do this:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(r.d), function (key, value) {
  if (value == 'Username') {
    $('#ddlcriteria1').val('Username');
  }
  else {
    $('#ddlcriteria1')
      .append($('<option>', { value: key })
        .text(value));
  }
});
```

Comment: the value for the <option> for "username" should be "3", but it did not get assigned to the option element for "username", the values for others got assigned correctly though.....I am not sure why doing "<option selected='selected'>" would omit assigning the value to the element.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code fixed :

```
$.each(JSON.parse(r.d), function (key, value) {
  if (value == 'Username') {
    $('#ddlcriteria1')
      .append($('<option>', { value: key, selected: "selected" })
        .text(value));
  }
  else {
    $('#ddlcriteria1')
      .append($('<option>', { value: key })
        .text(value));
  }
});
```

You should set the `selected` attribute in the array in the second parameter of the `append` function.

Comment: Why all those downvotes suddenly on various answers of this post ? Please explain why this answers are wrong.